# Paraview. Volume fraction and/or mass flow rate

Tags: data-visualization, paraview

My goal is to achieve something that was previously asked in [this site (outside from SO)](http://www.cfdem.com/forums/volume-fraction-andor-mass-flow-rate). In this external site the questions is unanswered, and in order to give more visibility and to try to get an answer I translate it to here:

The issue is:

> I have a small simulation of particles flowing through a wire mesh structure, and I'm interested in calculating the mass flow rate and volume fraction of particles at certain cross sections. I *think* I understand how to calculate mass flow rate by setting up small regions and dumping particle count and velocity from that region. I assume that volume fraction works in a similar fashion, except I only need to know the size of my particles and my dump region.
>
> What I'm wondering is this - is it possible to do these things in Paraview? I can set up planes and slices and such, but I can't seem to extract much useful information out of them.
>
> Further on down the road, what I would like to do would be to plot contours of volume fraction at certain planes, and plot the volume fraction along the vertical axis so I can see how high the particles are piling up on top of the screen, based on particle size, wire size, etc. Can Paraview do any of this?

This is a visualization issue. I don't know how make it with Paraview. The idea is count how much particles cross the slice.

My first approach was piped:  `DataReader | Spherical Glyph | Slice with normal fixed handly along z axis` but nothing results. Also I tried to adding the filter `Surface Flow` and nothing too. Probably I am piping the data in a bad way.

To see the pipelining process I add an image (focus in PlotOverLine1 and its above pipes):

[image: Image of ParaView]

Comment: Can we see what you've tried? Is this a programming issue, or a mathematical one?

Comment: Is a programming issue. I don't know how do it with Paraview.  The idea is count how much particles cross the slice. So, I pipelined DataReader | Spherical Glyph | Slice with normal fixed handly along z axis and nothing. Also I tried to adding the filter Surface flow but probably I am using in a bad way. Probably I am using the piped data wrong. But I cann't find the issue yet.

Comment: OK, can you add the above into your question, using the edit button? More detail the better, really. If there is any code associated with what you've described (I don't know ParaView) then please add that too - there is a code formatting tool.

Comment: @halfer I have improved my question. Please let me know if something extra is missing or anything else

Comment: I can't see any code, though. I don't know this tool, but it looks like either this is not a programming question (in the sense that using a spreadsheet with some formulae is not really programming) or that it _is_ a programming question, but no code has yet been supplied. Is there anything else you can add?

Comment: My problem concerns on the usage of Surface Flow in Paraview , because the physics and mathematics I had clear. I am doing that within the Paraview GUI. For that reason I show the pipeline process that I am doing.